# Implement TableFilterDemo

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablefilter

I have a problem implementing this example in java, tableFilterDemo is a class that order and find with a textfield with each caracther that i write.
I have to connect to my database and load the table with this data but the mytablemodel that this example implement is not compatible for me.
I tryed for differents ways. I need other ways to implement this example. I dont find other example to do this.

```
public class TableFilterDemo extends JPanel {

private boolean DEBUG = false;
private JTable table;
private JTextField filterText;
private JTextField statusText;
private TableRowSorter<MyTableModel> sorter;

public TableFilterDemo() {
    super();
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    //Create a table with a sorter.
    MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModel>(model);
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    //For the purposes of this example, better to have a single
    //selection.
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    //When selection changes, provide user with row numbers for
    //both view and model.
    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
            new ListSelectionListener() {

                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                    int viewRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if (viewRow < 0) {
                        //Selection got filtered away.
                        statusText.setText("");
                    } else {
                        int modelRow =
                                table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRow);
                        statusText.setText(
                                String.format("Selected Row in view: %d. "
                                + "Selected Row in model: %d.",
                                viewRow, modelRow));
                    }
                }
            });


    //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
    add(scrollPane);

    //Create a separate form for filterText and statusText
    JPanel form = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Filter Text:", SwingConstants.TRAILING);
    form.add(l1);
    filterText = new JTextField();
    //Whenever filterText changes, invoke newFilter.
    filterText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
            new DocumentListener() {

                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }

                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }

                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }
            });
    l1.setLabelFor(filterText);
    form.add(filterText);
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Status:", SwingConstants.TRAILING);
    form.add(l2);
    statusText = new JTextField();
    l2.setLabelFor(statusText);
    form.add(statusText);
    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(form, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6);
    add(form);
}

/** 
 * Update the row filter regular expression from the expression in
 * the text box.
 */
private void newFilter() {
    RowFilter<MyTableModel, Object> rf = null;
    //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0);
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
        "Last Name",
        "Sport",
        "# of Years",
        "Vegetarian"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith",
            "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
        {"John", "Doe",
            "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Sue", "Black",
            "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
        {"Jane", "White",
            "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown",
            "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
    };

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    /*
     * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
     * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
     * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
     * rather than a check box.
     */
    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * editable.
     */
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
        //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
        if (col < 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * data can change.
     */
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                    + " to " + value
                    + " (an instance of "
                    + value.getClass() + ")");
        }

        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("New value of data:");
            printDebugData();
        }
    }

    private void printDebugData() {
        int numRows = getRowCount();
        int numCols = getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                System.out.print("  " + data[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableFilterDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    TableFilterDemo newContentPane = new TableFilterDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the mytablemodel that this example implement is not compatible for me

The example should work for any TableModel.

If the MyTableModel doesn't store data the way you want then don't use it.

Use the DefaultTableModel or any custom model you have created.

Comment: i was trying this but i dont know how filter the table when a character is written in the textfield it is my problem, in the web i have one example. i want to do the same example and adapt to the logic of tableFilterDemo in http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. Either you let your TableModel communicate with your database directly.
2. Or you can cache your database (if it is small enough, which means that if you don't have any idea of the DB size, this is not a proper approach).

Example for #1 (I just show how I would implement the getRowCount() method, I let you do the other methods):

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private final Connection connection;

    private final String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };
    private final Object[][] data = {
            { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false) },
            { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) },
            { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false) },
            { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true) },
            { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };

    public MyTableModel() throws SQLException {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://[host][:port]/[database]");
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        int rowCount = 0;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM <YourTable>");
            if (rs.next()) {
                rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        return rowCount;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: my first problem is the object data. i cant bring the initial data from the BD or arraylist, i need solve this problem. I want to have the same funtionality that this page, on tableFilterDemo http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/